# Unable to remove dynamically inserted elements by LiveValidation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit, livevalidation

I'm using Live Validation plugin to validate my form. And when the form is submitted, the plugin adds in this line of code after the <input>:

`<span class=" LV_validation_message LV_valid">Ok</span>`

That's all fine, but when I submit the form, I want to reset the form for the next user. Here's my code:

```
$('#myForm').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var inputsValid = email.form.onsubmit();//apparently this checks that all fields are valid: name, phone, email
    if(inputsValid){
        $(this).remove('.LV_validation_message');
        //do stuff like send data to backend here...
        hideMyForm();
    }
});
```

As you can see, once I verify that the fields are ok, I will attempt to remove the validated messages by removing elements with the class 'LV_validation_message'. After which, I will hide the form. The next time the next user comes to the page, I will show the form again - only the `$(this).remove('.LV_validation_message')` line doesn't work, and the second user sees the validation messages stuck there to the form, even though the input fields are reset and are empty.

I started off with `$('#myForm').submit`, but changed it to `$('#myForm').on('submit')`, because I know `<span class=" LV_validation_message LV_valid">Ok</span>` is added dynamically. And I tried using `$(this).remove('.LV_validation_message')`, `$('.LV_validation_message'.remove()`, and even `$('.LV_validation_message'.html("")` - anything to change the elements with LV_validation_message class, but to no avail. These elements just seemed completely outside the control of jQuery.

Can somebody provide me with some hint or idea as to why I simply can't remove these elements? Here's the form in question, just in case:

```
<form id="myForm" autocomplete="off" class="tcenter">
    <label name="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off"><div class="LV-arrow-left-red">   </div><div class="LV-arrow-left-green"></div><br>
    <label name="phone">Phone</label>
    <input id="phone" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off"><div class="LV-arrow-left-red"></div><div class="LV-arrow-left-green"></div><br>
    <label name="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off"><div class="LV-arrow-left-red"></div><div class="LV-arrow-left-green"></div><br>
    <label><!-- Empty tag; to maintain layout --></label>
    <input class="ui-keyboard-button" type="image" width="297" height="64" alt="Submit">
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Play with firebug or similar, to see what exactly needs removing

Comment: I know exactly what needs to be removed. (And yes, I did use Firebug.) However, the problem is that jQuery just doesn't seem capable of removing them somehow. :(

Comment: see my answer and jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

try`$('.LV_validation_message').val("")`

or the error may be improper closing of input tags,should be

```
 <input id="name" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off"><div class="LV-arrow-left-red">   </div><div class="LV-arrow-left-green"></div></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work  `$('.LV_validation_message').remove()`

see my fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/4c8c4/